# How to transform matrix into numeric matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have made a scoring matrix in text file for local alignment with pairwiseAlignment function. Then I used this function to input it into the R:

```
ex <- as.matrix(read.table("~/scoringMatrix", header=FALSE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1, as.is=TRUE)
```

Format is this:

```
> ex

   A  T  C  G
A  5 -2 -1 -2
T -2  7 -1 -2
C -1 -1  7  2
G -2 -2  2  8
```

Now whenever I use `pairwiseAlignment` function I get following error:

```
pairwiseAlignment(x[[1]], x[[2]], substitutionMatrix = ex, gapOpening = -2, gapExtension = -8, scoreOnly = FALSE)
    Error in XStringSet.pairwiseAlignment(pattern = pattern, subject = subject,  : 
      'substitutionMatrix' must be a numeric matrix
```

If I would use already existing substitution matrix like BLOSUM50, it works perfectly. So how do I make this matrix suitable for pairwiseAlignment?

```
> dput(ex)
structure(logical(0), .Dim = c(5L, 0L), .Dimnames = list(c("   A  T  C  G", 
"A  5 -2 -1 -2", "T -2  7 -1 -2", "C -1 -1  7  2", "G -2 -2  2  8"
), NULL))
```

While `dput(BLOSUM50)` looks completely different:

```
> dput(BLOSUM50)
structure(c(5L, -2L, -1L, -2L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, -2L, -1L, -2L, 
-1L, -1L, -3L, -1L, 1L, 0L, -3L, -2L, 0L, -2L, -1L, -1L, -5L, 
-2L, 7L, -1L, -2L, -4L, 1L, 0L, -3L, 0L, -4L, -3L, 3L, -2L, -3L, 
-3L, -1L, -1L, -3L, -1L, -3L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -5L, -1L, -1L, 7L, 
2L, -2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -3L, -4L, 0L, -2L, -4L, -2L, 1L, 0L, 
-4L, -2L, -3L, 4L, 0L, -1L, -5L, -2L, -2L, 2L, 8L, -4L, 0L, 2L, 
-1L, -1L, -4L, -4L, -1L, -4L, -5L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -5L, -3L, -4L, 
5L, 1L, -1L, -5L, -1L, -4L, -2L, -4L, 13L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, 
-2L, -2L, -3L, -2L, -2L, -4L, -1L, -1L, -5L, -3L, -1L, -3L, -3L, 
-2L, -5L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -3L, 7L, 2L, -2L, 1L, -3L, -2L, 2L, 
0L, -4L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -3L, 0L, 4L, -1L, -5L, -1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, -3L, 2L, 6L, -3L, 0L, -4L, -3L, 1L, -2L, -3L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -3L, -2L, -3L, 1L, 5L, -1L, -5L, 0L, -3L, 0L, -1L, 
-3L, -2L, -3L, 8L, -2L, -4L, -4L, -2L, -3L, -4L, -2L, 0L, -2L, 
-3L, -3L, -4L, -1L, -2L, -2L, -5L, -2L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -3L, 1L, 
0L, -2L, 10L, -4L, -3L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -1L, -2L, -3L, 2L, 
-4L, 0L, 0L, -1L, -5L, -1L, -4L, -3L, -4L, -2L, -3L, -4L, -4L, 
-4L, 5L, 2L, -3L, 2L, 0L, -3L, -3L, -1L, -3L, -1L, 4L, -4L, -3L, 
-1L, -5L, -2L, -3L, -4L, -4L, -2L, -2L, -3L, -4L, -3L, 2L, 5L, 
-3L, 3L, 1L, -4L, -3L, -1L, -2L, -1L, 1L, -4L, -3L, -1L, -5L, 
-1L, 3L, 0L, -1L, -3L, 2L, 1L, -2L, 0L, -3L, -3L, 6L, -2L, -4L, 
-1L, 0L, -1L, -3L, -2L, -3L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -5L, -1L, -2L, -2L, 
-4L, -2L, 0L, -2L, -3L, -1L, 2L, 3L, -2L, 7L, 0L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 
-1L, 0L, 1L, -3L, -1L, -1L, -5L, -3L, -3L, -4L, -5L, -2L, -4L, 
-3L, -4L, -1L, 0L, 1L, -4L, 0L, 8L, -4L, -3L, -2L, 1L, 4L, -1L, 
-4L, -4L, -2L, -5L, -1L, -3L, -2L, -1L, -4L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -2L, 
-3L, -4L, -1L, -3L, -4L, 10L, -1L, -1L, -4L, -3L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 
-2L, -5L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -3L, -3L, 0L, 
-2L, -3L, -1L, 5L, 2L, -4L, -2L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, -5L, 0L, -1L, 
0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -2L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -1L, 
2L, 5L, -3L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, -5L, -3L, -3L, -4L, -5L, -5L, 
-1L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -2L, -3L, -1L, 1L, -4L, -4L, -3L, 15L, 
2L, -3L, -5L, -2L, -3L, -5L, -2L, -1L, -2L, -3L, -3L, -1L, -2L, 
-3L, 2L, -1L, -1L, -2L, 0L, 4L, -3L, -2L, -2L, 2L, 8L, -1L, -3L, 
-2L, -1L, -5L, 0L, -3L, -3L, -4L, -1L, -3L, -3L, -4L, -4L, 4L, 
1L, -3L, 1L, -1L, -3L, -2L, 0L, -3L, -1L, 5L, -4L, -3L, -1L, 
-5L, -2L, -1L, 4L, 5L, -3L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, -4L, -4L, 0L, -3L, 
-4L, -2L, 0L, 0L, -5L, -3L, -4L, 5L, 2L, -1L, -5L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, -3L, 4L, 5L, -2L, 0L, -3L, -3L, 1L, -1L, -4L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 
-2L, -2L, -3L, 2L, 5L, -1L, -5L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -1L, 
-1L, -2L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -2L, -2L, -1L, 0L, -3L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, 
-5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, -5L, 
-5L, -5L, 1L), .Dim = c(24L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "R", 
"N", "D", "C", "Q", "E", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", 
"S", "T", "W", "Y", "V", "B", "Z", "X", "*"), c("A", "R", "N", 
"D", "C", "Q", "E", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", 
"T", "W", "Y", "V", "B", "Z", "X", "*")))
```

Comment: Does `apply(x, 2, as.numeric)` work?

Comment: @TadDallas did you mean `ex2 <- apply(ex, 2, as.numeric)`? This does not work if that's what you meant.

Comment: are you sure you want `header=FALSE`, as you appear to have a header `A  T  C  G`. If so, using`header=FALSE`  will make the first row of your matrix these labels, hence your matrix will be `character`

Comment: Please provide `dput(ex)` and all your problems will be instantly solved.

Comment: @user20650 well if it's TRUE then I don't have first row, which is needed for comparison. David, I updated OP with dput.

Comment: Wow `ex` is a very strange data structure which containing solely dimnames

Comment: @DavidArenburg well all I did was used the function in my OP to input that matrix from text file containing matrix in exact same format.

Comment: Did yo try reading it with a different `sep`? Either way, the following is a messed up fix `temp <- na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(dimnames(ex)[[1]], " ")))) ; matrix(temp, ncol = 4)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I still get `'substitutionMatrix' must be a numeric matrix` whenever I use new matrix into pairwiseAlignment.

Comment: Did you save `matrix(temp, ncol = 4)` in some new object? Either we need to fix the way you are reading the data in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77458/discussion-between-estranged-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your 'scoringMatrix' file has *space delimited* columns, and that its input is just

```
ex = as.matrix(read.delim("scoringMatrix", sep=""))
```

which has structure

```
> dput(ex)
structure(c(5L, -2L, -1L, -2L, -2L, 7L, -1L, -2L, -1L, -1L, 7L, 
2L, -2L, -2L, 2L, 8L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
"T", "C", "G"), c("A", "T", "C", "G")))
```

In your input, there were no tab characters `\t` so each line was read in as a single column. And `row.names=1` means that the single column is assigned as row names -- so you've got 5 rows and zero columns

```
> read.table("scoringMatrix", sep="\t", header=FALSE, row.names=1)
data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
```

Coercing this to a matrix results in a 5 x 0 matrix, and what you see in your original display are the row names (!) of the matrix.

This could be created in R 'by hand', as suggested by @DavidArenburg with

```
matrix(c( 5, -2, -1, -2,
         -2,  7, -1, -2,
         -1, -1,  7,  2,
         -2, -2,  2,  8),
       nrow=4, ncol=4,
       dimnames=list(
         c("A", "C", "G", "T"),
         c("A", "C", "G", "T")),
       byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: OP actually created this matrix by hand using a text editor. Another option would be to just create a similar matrix using R. Something like `head(BLOSUM50[, 1:4], 4)`

Comment: That not exactly what I meant. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to just select the desired column/rows from  `BLOSUM50` using `match` and avoid creating this file manually using a text editor in the first place

```
indx <- match(c("A", "T", "C", "G"), rownames(BLOSUM50))
BLOSUM50[indx, indx]
#    A  T  C  G
# A  5  0 -1  0
# T  0  5 -1 -2
# C -1 -1 13 -3
# G  0 -2 -3  8
```